# Excel 2010 - Shape Hyperlink to point to a Cell Text URL

Tags: excel, url, hyperlink, shapes

Say in cell Z1, I have the URL: http://www.microsoft.com

And, I have a rectangle shape near A1… and I want it to have a hyperlink… and the URL for the hyperlink should be the URL in cell Z1.

So, when someone clicking the Rect will be taken to http://www.microsoft.com

When the URL is changed in cell Z1 to say http://www.yahoo.com

Now, when clicking the Rect should take him to the new URL.

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know i don't think you can set up a hyperlink like this on a *shape*.

But you could use a Formula:  `=HYPERLINK(Z1,"Go Here")`